# Drupal 7 Field Collection View Not Grouping Correctly

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-field-collection

The grouping of field collections doesn't appear to be working correctly.

### **Fields:**

- Item
- Sub-item
- Sub-sub-item

### **Relationships:**

- Sub-item with Sub-sub-item

### **What's displaying:**

**With Delta 2:**

1. Item 1 

1.1

1.2

1.2.1

1.2.2

 **With Delta All**

1. Item 1 

1.1

1.2

1.1.1

1. Item 1

1.1

1.2

1.2.1

1.2.2

It appears it doesn't know that 1.1.1 belongs under 1.1.  Can it be since t was typed in after everything else was?  Without the relationship the sub-sub-item doesn't appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
Very simple. In the **view (field collection view) clone** have:

 1. The first collection item

2. The second collection item (whole collection)

*No relationships are necessary*

**Field Collection setup:**

1. In the second collection item show the third collection item through field collection items in the display.

2. In the third level make sure the necessary fields are showing.

**Styling:**

The third level won't be styled so will have to style this is what I did:

```
.field-collection-container {
 border-bottom: 0px solid #D3D7D9; /*changed to 0 */
 margin-bottom: 0.5em; /*changed from 0*/
 }

.field-collection-view {
padding: 0.5em 0 0.3em 0; /*was 1em 0 0 0.3em 0*/
margin: 0 0 0 1em;
border-bottom: 0px dotted #D3D7D9; /*changed to 0*/
}

.field-collection-container .field-items .field-items .field-item {
margin-bottom: -1em; /*changed from 0*/
}
```